# Hardware choosing and Bandwidth limitations on NGINX reverse proxy on a VPS?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, https, bandwidth

Good afternoon friends.

We are currently growing our infrastructure of a SaaS application and require 2 app dedicated servers, each running multiple instances of a nodejs application.

The company where we are hosting the servers does provide an IP load balancer 'off the shelf', but apparently cannot handle HTTPS at this point, so we need to actually build the load balancer (reverse proxy) ourselves.  They have suggested to use a cheap VPS and configure ourselves an NGINX with a reverse proxy and SSL termination.

I am fairly new to this and have been doing a lot of reading, but still have some questions:

- What would be a good 'size' for the VPS to handle the reverse proxy?
- Is the decryption/encryption of SSL more memory, CPU or I/O tasking chore? Which should I prioritize?
- The actual application servers have a nice 512Mbps bandwidth with a 1Gbps burst, but the VPS that will be doing all the client communications has actually only 100Mbps. Is this an issue?
- Perhaps the servers can be configured to reply directly to the client instead of going 'back' to the VPS? Is this even possible or desirable?

So, my issues are really that I was hopping for an 'off the shelf' solution, and now that I need to configure everything manually, I'm a bit concerned about the actual requirements I need and how to configure them.

Any advice on how to approach basic SSL Load Balancing would be appreciated.  If the approach I'm taking is completely wrong, I'm open to all and every suggestion.

Thanks in advance, best regards,

Rafa Pólit.